# How to get Range when using angular ui ace?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ace-editor

Does anyone know how i can get Range with angular ui ace?
If i am directly embedding ace in my html, i could probably do something like this:

```
var editor = ace.edit("editor");
editor.setTheme("ace/theme/monokai");
editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/javascript");

    var Range = ace.require('ace/range').Range;
```

But how can i get this with angular ui ace? I have access to the model and the Editor class, but i guess this will require the ace object?

[Ace documentation](http://ace.c9.io/#api=ace&nav=api)

[angular ui ace](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-ace)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ace global variable is available with angular ui ace too.
Try `ace.require('ace/range').Range;` in the console on ui-ace demo page http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-ace/

Comment: Does not work under ui-ace. There is no access to ace object.

Comment: what do you mean? there is a global ace object on that page

Comment: Sorry, you are right. It seams that ace object is the "editor" object mentioned in my answer bellow. But the problem is, that we just can't call require method on ace object when using ui-ace :(. We are probably missing something and it's the reason of original question.

Comment: maybe you are creating a new ace object which shadows the global one? could you try window.ace

Answer (score 0):

I just found solution. I don't love it, but it works!

For creating new Range object, you need to get its constructor. And because the selectionRange property of the editor is the same "object type" (I know, we are in JavaScript), you can get its constructor and create new Range object with that :)

You can get editor object in the onLoad function:

```
this.aceLoaded = function (editor) {
    let AceRange = editor.getSelectionRange().constructor;
    editor.session.addMarker(new AceRange(from,0, to, 200), "your-style", "fullLine");
}
```

and in the html template, you bind it with

```
  <div ui-ace="{
          onLoad: $ctrl.aceLoaded,
        }">
```